Turing completeness of a string rewriting system with $n$ rules
I have read that a rewriting system can be turing complete.
I became curious about the minimum number of rules needed to achieve this - in string rewriting systems to be specific.
However, I could not find any related study online. Is there a bound on n where a string rewriting system with n rules is turing complete?
